# Android Google Cloud Messaging register id change

Tags: android

I have an issue yesterday i got Google Cloud Messaging register id and today i have got different Google Cloud Messaging register id.

So is it true or not one Android device has different Google Cloud Messaging register id?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Implementing a GCM Client documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#reg-errors):

> A given regID is not guaranteed to last indefinitely, so the first thing your app should always do is check to make sure it has a valid regID (as shown in the code snippets above).

Note also the [Keeping the Registration State in Sync](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#reg-state) advanced section on Canonical registration ids:

> On the server side, as long as the application is behaving well, everything should work normally. However, if a bug in the application triggers multiple registrations for the same device, it can be hard to reconcile state and you might end up with duplicate messages.
>
> GCM provides a facility called "canonical registration IDs" to easily recover from these situations. A canonical registration ID is defined to be the ID of the last registration requested by your application. This is the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the device.
>
> If later on you try to send a message using a different registration ID, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the response. Make sure to replace the registration ID stored in your server with this canonical ID, as eventually the ID you're using will stop working.

In summary, you should always use the latest registration id you receive - any previously received ones are not guaranteed to continue to work.